# How can the collection be accessed during a Ramda map?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Given a very simple example:

```
R.map((a, b) => {
  console.log(a, b) // 1, undefined
}, [1, 2, 3])
```

How can I access the collection as a whole within the map?

A contrived example of using the collection might be:

```
R.map((item, collection) => {
  console.log(item === collection.length)
}, [1, 2, 3])
```

I could store it in a variable prior, but this is at the end of a chain of functions

Comment: You can't, because you usually shouldn't need to. Your example is quite contrived indeed.

Comment: Hmm, when I said contrived, I meant more a simplified example to illustrate the point rather than something that couldn't happen.

Comment: Yes, but if you present a real problem we can figure out a real solution, maybe even different from the standard "introduce a binding".

Comment: That's fair. I feel like that can go two ways when asking questions on SO - some people add _way too_ much "context" which muddies the water around what is truely being ask. In this case, even though its not the actual solution I was looking for, the question abstracts away the content not needed. In other words, I was trying to build up my own understanding of _why_ it works, then in turn solve the business problem it was blocking

Comment: @Chris, there's nothing wrong with that approach, but Bergi is correct that most of the time when people ask for this, their underlying problem can be solved with other techniques.  And there are good reasons for not including it.  So, even if [`R.addIndex`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#addIndex) works for you, it might be useful to explain the real problem to see if there are better methods to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have suggested, there are good reasons Ramda does not include this by default.  But there is a decorator called [`addIndex`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#addIndex) which adds the index and collection:

```
const fn = R.addIndex(map)((elt, idx, coll) => elt == coll.length);
fn([1, 2, 3]); //=> [false, false, true]
```

Comment: This is perfect! I'm still 100% sure why its not included, comments have suggested there are reasons, but I will need to go figure out what that why actually is

Comment: I long, and sometimes heated, discussion of the reasons behind this can be found in [Ramda Issue #452](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/452).

Comment: That's a very, hmm, interesting discussion. Interestingly enough - one of our apps is 50/50 lodash/ramda, and in the midst of converting a few functions across to ramda, my question above popped up. I'm not here to get into any debate, so I'm going to thank you for the answer and carry on about my day.

Answer (score 2):

`R.map` doesn't give you access to the collection inside the mapping function, but you could create a closure around the mapping function in order to give yourself an opportunity to assign a name to the collection.

```
((collection) => R.map((item) => {
  console.log(item === collection.length)
}, collection))([1, 2, 3]);
```

Comment: Cool - that will work. Is there a thought process around the _why_ its not included? I'm coming from lodash, curious at its omission

Comment: The "why" is probably just because that's the signature of a traditional `map` in functional programming. This is where studying other functional programming languages would help to give some more background on why things are the way they are.